# Passing input state around in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state

I have a react class that has this code:

```
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      results: false,
      value: ''
    };
  },

  handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({ results: true });
    event.preventDefault();
  },

  handleChange: function(event){
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  },

    <input type="text" id="playerName" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="name" />
```

IN ANOTHER REACT CLASS

I have:

```
myFunc: function() {
    this.setState({info: true})
    let name = this.props.value;
    console.log(name) --> returns undefined
  },
```

How can I name to be equal to the name that the user typed in by passing it down from one react class to another

I can post more code but I thought props was the way to pass down code you needed elsewhere. `this.state.value` also returns undefined

edit:

myFunc called here:

```
<input type="submit" value="I can play" onClick={() => this.myFunc()}/>
```

Comment: You need to bind `this` in `handleChange` method explicitly like this `this.handleChange.bind(this)`. Try this and yes post more code if it still doesn't work, may be try Codepen to put your whole code on it.

Comment: @BasimHennawi No, not with `createClass`.  That would be a problem if the OP was using react components with `class`.

Comment: How does `this.props.value` get set?  Can you show the component that uses `myFunc`?

Comment: @DavinTryon added one more line to show where I call myFunc, anything else you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for this to work is to have a container component, this container component would handle all state management and wrap around child components:

```
<WrapperComponent>
 <Input/>
 <Info />
</WrapperComponent
```

Your input can still have its own state if you want to do debouncing and things like that but the wrapper component will have its own functions that set its own state and it passes those functions down to input so that input can call them with its new values and then the wrapper component will update and then the Info component will receive its value props from the wrapper component and everything will be in sync.

here is an example codepen http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/VKPXoN

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {    
  constructor() {
  super();
    this.state = {
      value: 'default'
    }
  }

  _handleChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({value: value})  
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Input onChange={this._handleChange} value={this.state.value}/>
       <Info value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.value
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
  }
}

const Info = (props) => {
  return (
   <h1> {props.value} </h1>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

obviously you can easily convert this to using the `createClass` version doesn't have to be using es6 version. The main take away here is that if you want to share values across components that aren't directly related then you definitely are going to want a state container component that is handling everything.

Here is a great article going over container vs presentational components https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: I think I get this. but the problem is this setting the value on screen as soon as i type it out. i.e on code pen when I edited the text box it showed it underneath. I want something more like, the user enters a number a value into the text box, they hit submit and then I can call that submitted value other places in the code..

Comment: does that make sense??

Comment: You would just update the input component to have a button and instead of passing in a onChange function as props do an onSubmit function. The idea would still be the same that you would have the WrapperComponent be updated once the submit takes place. If you want it outside of the WrapperComponent you would need to use something like Redux which provides stores components can subscribe to

Comment: I updated the pen form to use submit button http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/VKPXoN